# Inno Setup IDE window does not open

Tags: windows, inno-setup

I used to create an installation file with Inno Setup on Windows 10. However, now the program does open neither old nor new script files. I reinstalled the program but the IDE window does not open. I can run the script wizard but that's it. There is an icon in the task bar, but nothing happens when I click on it.

Running Inno Setup 6.1.2

Comment: If I had to guess it sounds like the window is off the screen. If that's the case, you should be able to right-click the taskbar button and choose "Move," then use the arrow keys to reposition the window until it shows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Try deleting Inno Setup settings from registry at:
  `[HKCU\SOFTWARE\Jordan Russell\Inno Setup]`
- Make sure the Inno Setup window does does start on a different monitor, which you might have turned off or disconnected.

Comment: Ok, I attached a monitor and there was the window. The program is not pushed to the available desktop but stores the coordinates of a former session, even if no secondary monitor is present.